# Laravel: Convert mySQL data ONLY as migration scripts

Tags: mysql, laravel-4, database-migration

As the title suggests, is there a way that we can convert existing mySQL data from select tables into migration scripts?

Anyone? Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

Using laravel migration will only allow you to modify database schema and stay up-to-date. But if you want to seed some of your existing mysql data, then use database seeding.

reference: http://laravel.com/docs/migrations#database-seeding

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I'm not asking about seeding. My question is about conversion of existing mySQL tables into migration scripts.

Comment: I thought you were asking about normal db seedings. Anyways if you want to convert your existing mySQL tables to migration scripts, please follow this link: http://laravelsnippets.com/snippets/convert-an-existing-mysql-database-to-migrations.

Comment: Ugh, again I'm asking about converting the DATA not the structure.